# Is $\{f(x_n^2)\}$ a Cauchy sequence if $|x_n-x_{n+1}|<\frac{1}{10^n}$ and $f$ is continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

Let $\{x_n\}$ be a sequence in $\Bbb R$ that satisfies
$$|x_n-x_{n+1}|<\frac{1}{10^n}\tag{$*$}$$
for each $n$, and let $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ be continuous. I'd like to determine **whether $\{f(x_n^2)\}$ is a Cauchy sequence**.

It occurred to me that continuity preserves sequential limits, so I decide to consider the continuous function $f\circ g$ with $g:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ defined by $g(x)=x^2$. Now $\{x_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\Bbb R$, which can be easily verified by an application of ($*$). Therefore, $\{x_n\}$ is a convergent sequence, and so is $\{(f\circ g)(x_n)\}$, which in turn tells us that $\{f(x_n^2)\}$ is a Cauchy sequence. Is my approach correct? Thank you.

Comment: This is a good proof. One detail is (probably) missing: how do you know that $(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence? (It can be easily proven, but you have omitted the proof. If this is part of some exercise that would be marked, then some marks would be probably awarded or lost for that step.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, the image of a Cauchy sequence under a continuous function is not a Cauchy sequence. But here you can use that continuous functions preserve sequential limits and that the domain of the function is complete: The Cauchy sequence converges to some point $x_*$ in the domain of the function; now you can use that the function is continuous at $x_*$, and therefore the image of the sequence converges to the image of $x_*$ and is therefore a Cauchy sequence.

Answer (score 0):

$f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R} $ continuous.

$(x_n) $ cauchy implies $(x_n) $ convergent due to completeness of $\mathbb{R}$

$(x_n) $ convergent implies $(x_n) ^2 $ convergent.

A continuous function maps convergent sequence to convergent sequence.

$f((x_n) ^2) $ is also convergent.

And every convergent sequence is cauchy.

Implies, $f((x_n) ^2) $ is cauchy.